# Функция c аргументом %2x

Tags: ассемблер, reverse-engineering

Не могу понять, что делает данная функция:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она же изнутри:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Принимает 3 аргумента, после ее выполнения 3-й аргумент изменяется.

Если мы заносим туда следующие данные:

- Первый аргумент `eax=адресу 0012F920` по которому располагаются следующие значения: `62h,38h,33h,61h....` (по идее при первой итерации берется число `62h`)
- Второй аргумент `%2x`, по идее данный аргумент используется в функциях `printf` и `sprintf`  для отображения контента в hex виде, минимум 2 числа.
- 3-й аргумент является адресом указывающим на "мусор" до выполнения функции, после выполнения по адресу указанному в 3-м аргументе появляется число `0B8h` (при `eax` указывающим на `62h`, при другом eax другое значение 3-го аргумента). т.е  `f(62h)=0B8h`

По аргументам функция похожа на `sprintf`, но у  `sprintf` принимающий буфер идет первым аргументом, а также `sprintf` заполнил бы буфер значениями `54h,50h` ( а не `0B8h`) как сейчас. Подскажите, что это может быть?

Comment: scanf например и ее аналоги

Comment: Подскажите, почему я тогда получаю unknown_function(62h)=0B8h

Comment: Значит это некая внутренняя служебная функция, а dll или где оно там находится собрана без отладочной информации и соответственно имена взять не откуда

Comment: но раз 3 аргумента, то может sscanf (я же сказал, scanf и ее аналоги, коих для разных случаев жизни наберется с десяток)

Comment: Ну вообще это [sscanf](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/sscanf) скорее всего и есть. Порядок аргументов правда как-то не очень логичен. Первый аргумент (разбираемая строка) - в eax, второй параметр (строка форматирования) - в стеке, а 3-й - в ecx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это функция подобная [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/), обратная функциям `printf` и `sprintf`: на входе готовая строка, которую нужно разобрать, строка форматирования (согласно которой разбираем), адреса переменных-получателей.

Если на входе строка `"b83a"`, строка разбора `"%2x"`, то каждая пара символов из исходной строки должна разбираться как шестнадцатеричное число, т.е. на первой итерации в буфер должно попасть `0xB8`, на второй - `0x3A`.

Пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char input[] = {0x62, 0x38, 0x33, 0x61, 0};  // Символы "b83a"
    char * p = input;
    int number;
    while(p[0]) {
        sscanf(p, "%2x", &number);
        printf("0x%2X\n", number);
        p += 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
0xB8
0x3A
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/6vgPnR)

Т.е. исходная строка `"b83a"` разобралась на два числа: `0xB8`, `0x3A`.